# Welcome screen no longer appears after a recent update

Tags: greeter, desktop

a few updates back the welcome screen was updated but after this the welcome screen no longer appears (which is great as I found it annoying).
So I also performed a fresh install on another pc and the welcome screen was working but the most recent update broke it on that pc too.
Just raising as an issue for the devs, I am sure other people have had this too

Comment: I'm not sure it's entirely clear what you mean by welcome screen. Do you mean a small window with the introduction to the system?

Comment: yes the small welcome screen (with the green circle icon) after logging in

Comment: That is only intended to run the first time you start up your machine. It is a feature called [onboarding](https://blog.elementary.io/get-settled-into-elementary-os-with-onboarding/) and "It's intentional that this is shown every boot for early access. On a stable install it will only show once" - [Danrabbit](https://github.com/elementary/onboarding/issues/134#issuecomment-852271532)